# Почему не сохраняется данные по шаблону в PHPword?

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

***контроллер***

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Exception;
use App\Histori;
use \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
class WordCon extends Controller
{
    public function generateDocx()
    {
        $phpWord = new PhpWord;
        $document = $phpWord->loadTemplate(storage_path('Test.docx'));
        $document->setValue('data', '777');
        $document->save('Tet.docx');
        return response()->download(storage_path('Tet.docx'));
    }
}
```

***это ворд-шаблон с переменной***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> мне нужно чтобы когда я скачиваю уже сохраненный файл(Tet.docx)
>   который был заполнен по шаблону (Test.docx) при открытие он пуст а
>   должен быть заполнено таким предложением (тест 777) но он пуст в чем
>   ошибка ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$document = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('Путь\Test.docx');

$document->setValue('data', '777');

$document->saveAs('documents\result.docx');
```

Пример: [Тут](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.php)